# Can the expression $a^2 + b^2 - c^2$ be factored as a product of two quaternions, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quaternions

I'm trying to factor the expression
$$a^2+b^2-c^2$$
as a product of two quaternions, where $a,b,c$ are reals. Can anyone give me the answer?

---

I think it can't be done.
I started with multiplying
$$(Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd)(Ea,Fb,Gc,Hd)=\\
(a^2 A E - b^2 B F - c^2 C G - d^2 D H,\\
a b B E + a b B F - c d D G + c d C H, \\
a c C E + b d D F + a c A G - b d B H, \\
a d D E - b c C F + b c B G + a d A H)$$
For some real numbers $A, B, \dotsc, H$ , where I use the convention $(A,B,C,D)=A +Bi +Cj+Dk$. Since we want the result to be real for all $a,b,c,d$ we can write
$$D E + A  H = 0\\
C F - B  G = 0\\
C E + A  G =0\\
D F  -B  H = 0\\
 B E + A  F = 0\\
 D G - C  H = 0$$
What remains is to set the real part to be equal to the desired result.
For example if we choose the polynomial $a^2+b^2+c^2$ we get
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(0,a,b,c)(0,-a,-b,-c).$$
However, my question was to find the factorization for $$a^2+b^2-c^2.$$ In that case the system doesn't have any real solutions for $A,B,\dotsc,H$.

I suspect therefore that all the polynomials, where one sign differs from the others, e.g.
$$a^2-b^2+d^2\\
b^2+c^2-d^2$$
will also not be factorisable.
Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Your work begins with an unjustifiably narrow assumption from the start - that if there were a factorization, the factors would be of the form $Aa+(B{\bf i})b+(C{\bf j})c+(D\mathbf{k})d$. First, there is no point in introducing a new variable $d$ when the original polynomial doesn't have $d$, and second you're making assumptions about the putative coefficients of $a,b,c$. For instance, if you want to factor $a^2-b^2$ over the complex numbers, should you write it as $(Aa+Bib)(Ca+Dib)$ with $A,B,C,D$ real? No; you can't assume the coefficients of $a$ and $b$ are real/imaginary respectively.

Comment: And $a^2-b^2+d^2$ etc. are the same exact polynomial, just with different choice of variable names, so the same exact logic applies to them. Forget quaternions for a moment - if $a^2+b^2$ can be factored with complex numbers then so can $c^2+d^2$, just replace the letters, and similarly if $a^2+b^2$ cannot be factored with real numbers then neither can $c^2+d^2$.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. This is my first encounter with quaternions, so please forgive my mistakes. The assumption I made is indeed very narrow but I was just hoping for the best. Now that I know that the polynomial can be factored in split quaternions, I will focus on understanding them. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: It seems that it should be "abAF" instead of "abBF".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be written as the product of two $\mathbb{H}$-linear combinations of variables $a,b,c$. (We assume the formal variables commute with all quaternion scalars, of course.)

Suppose it were, say $(ap+q)(ar+s)$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{H}$ and $r,s$ are $\mathbb{H}$-linear combinations of $b$ and $c$. The leading term (with respect to $a$) would then be $pra^2$ which must be $a^2$ and so $pr=1$. We may factor the coefficients of $a$ out as $(a+qp^{-1})pr(a+r^{-1}s)=(a+u)(a+v)$. Now the middle term is $(u+v)a$, which must be $0$ as in the expression $a^2+b^2-c^2$, so $v=-u$ and we get $(a+u)(a-u)=a^2-u^2$. Thus, we want some combination of $b$ and $c$ (that is, $u$) which squares to $b^2-c^2$.

Writing $(xb+yc)^2=b^2-c^2$, we see $x^2=1$ so $x=\pm1$. But then the middle term is $\pm2ybc$ which can only be $0$ if $y=0$ in which case we don't see $-c^2$ as the final term.

It is however factorizable in the *split* quaternions. Then $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$ is the product of the split quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$ with its conjugate $a-bi-cj-dk$.

Comment: Thank you very, you managed to provide the answer while I was typing my progress. I'm also very grateful that you pointed out a possible factorisation in the split quaternions.