# Is ODE factorisation with split-quaternions possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factoring, quaternions

In [Simple complex ODE's in matrix form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667432/simple-complex-odes-in-matrix-form) we discussed how we can solve certain complex ODE's in matrix form. As an example:

$$y(x)^2+y'(x)^2=0$$

can be factored as
$$(y(x)+ iy'(x))(y(x)-iy'(x))=0$$

and if we insist we could solve the two above equations by representing each term in a matrix form, i.e.
$$y(x)\equiv \begin{pmatrix}y_r(x)&-y_i(x)\\y_i(x)& y_r(x)\end{pmatrix}\\
y'(x)\equiv \begin{pmatrix}y'_r(x)&-y'_i(x)\\y'_i(x)& y'_r(x)\end{pmatrix}\\
i \equiv  \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}\\ $$
Multiplying the matrices out we get a system of coupled ODE's and the solution is found.

However, I was trying to apply this technique for a different problem:

$$y(x)^2+y'(x)^2-1=0$$

This expression cannot be factored as a product of two complex numbers (except the trivial factoring of 1). However, I tried to factor it over different types of numbers and in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667291/can-the-expression-a2-b2-c2-be-factored-as-a-product-of-two-quaternions) we discussed, that split-quaternions allow the following factorisation:

$$(y(x)+i y'(x)+j)(y(x)-i y'(x)-j)=0$$

Just like regular complex numbers allow a representation by 2x2 real matrices, split-quaternions can be written as 2x2 complex matrices. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion). The true solution is:
$${y(x) = c_1\sin(x)}\\
 {y(x) = c_2\cos(x)}$$
and what we get from the method I developed is the following
$$y(x)= c_1 \cos(x)-c_2 \sin(x)+\\(c_1 \sin(x)+c_2 \cos(x))i+ \\(c_4 \sin(x)+c_3 \cos(x)-1)j+ \\(c_4 \cos(x)-c_3 \sin(x))k$$
So that $\mathcal{R}\{y(x)\}=c_1 \cos(x)-c_2 \sin(x)$ and the results agree.

My question is: when can I use this technique? Is it legitimate or is it just a lucky coincidence?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can do that with any [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra), of which complex numbers and split quaternions are examples. A similar idea leads to the concept of Dirac operators.